# PhoneGap / iOS LocalNotification App Crashes on tapping "View"

Tags: ios, cordova, uilocalnotification, localnotification

I'm having trouble here: I have the app set to not run in the background, and I'm setting a dailyInterval localnotification using a localNotification plugin I found on github here: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/LocalNotification

The app crashes when the notification pops up, and I tap "View"... looks like something is being sent along and it doesn't know what's going on. I, also don't know what's going on since Objective C is a foreign language to me. Anyone have any ideas?

```
--------- Console Log ----------
```

7/29/11 11:05:48 AM Afternoon Affirmations[12004]   -[UIConcreteLocalNotification absoluteString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5c22240

```
7/29/11 11:05:48 AM Afternoon Affirmations[12004]   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIConcreteLocalNotification absoluteString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5c22240'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x017f65a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0194a313 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x017f80bb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x01767966 ___forwarding___ + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x01767522 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    5   Afternoon Affirmations              0x00002f21 -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 257
    6   UIKit                               0x002f7c89 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1163
    7   UIKit                               0x002f9d88 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 439
    8   UIKit                               0x00304617 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1533
    9   UIKit                               0x002fcabf -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 71
    10  UIKit                               0x00301f2e _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576
    11  GraphicsServices                    0x020e5992 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x017d7944 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x01737cf7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x01734f83 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x01734840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x01734761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    17  UIKit                               0x002f97d2 -[UIApplication _run] + 623
    18  UIKit                               0x00305c93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    19  Afternoon Affirmations              0x00002d7f main + 127
    20  Afternoon Affirmations              0x00002cf5 start + 53
)

7/29/11 11:05:48 AM UIKitApplication:com.InTheRooms.AfternoonAffirmations[0x9a52][12004]    terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

Comment: It's not crashing when I set the app to run in the background (Application does not run in background = NO). But it's still crashing with this property if the app is no longer in the memory :-/

Comment: @SamuelMichelot I'm having trouble getting this plugin to work at all (no crashes, no notifications). Maybe I'm setting it up right. Could you help me out?

Comment: The plugin has been updated recently...

Comment: This seems to have been resolved in the latest version of Cordova.. The code in -application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: has been updated.

Answer (score 3):

OK, I found the problem, it's in the file AppDelegate.m and more precisely in the method : didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. The method assumes that the first option parameters is an url (but it's not when we launch the app via a Local Notification. The quick and dirty fix is to comment the code :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //commented out because it makes the app crash at startup with local notification...
    /*NSArray *keyArray = [launchOptions allKeys];
    if ([launchOptions objectForKey:[keyArray objectAtIndex:0]]!=nil) 
    {
        NSURL *url = [launchOptions objectForKey:[keyArray objectAtIndex:0]];
        self.invokeString = [url absoluteString];
        NSLog(@"Mosa_fr_en-busi launchOptions = %@",url);
    }*/

    return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've re-writen the localNotification plugin if anyone is interested - you can now add callbacks as well as sound. I like this fix for this problem as I have faced the same thing. I've also included it in the GIT project.

the GIT project
https://github.com/DrewDahlman/Phonegap-LocalNotification

and a blog post explaining changes 
http://www.drewdahlman.com/meusLabs/?p=117

Answer (score 0):

A little bit better solution is something like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSArray *keyArray = [launchOptions allKeys];
    if ([keyArray count] > 0) {
        id option = [launchOptions objectForKey:[keyArray objectAtIndex:0]];
        if ([option isKindOfClass:[NSURL class]]) {
            NSURL *url = (NSURL *)option;
            self.invokeString = [url absoluteString];
            NSLog(@"ContactInbox launchOptions = %@",url);
        }
    }

    return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}
```

If somebody knows what key PhoneGap expects to have for URL it's better to replace `[keyArray objectAtIndex:0]` part with actual key.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with local notifications. The solution that I chose is a bit different (though quite similar). I'm using a check for a local notification launch option (UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey).

Here is a short example:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];

    if( localNotif ) 
    {
        // Do whatever you need to do with that local notitication
    }
    else
    {
        NSArray *keyArray = [launchOptions allKeys];
        if ([launchOptions objectForKey:[keyArray objectAtIndex:0]]!=nil) 
        {
            NSURL *url = [launchOptions objectForKey:[keyArray objectAtIndex:0]];
            self.invokeString = [url absoluteString];
        }
    }
    return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}
```

Apple Docs:
    http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html