# Local Notification in Phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, localnotification

I want to have a local notification in my iOS Phonegap app. I followed lots of tutorials and code but no help. Can anyone please guide me.

Comment: Could you please give us some example code? Or maybe a reference to the tutorials that you have used? Otherwise it might be hard to find what you are doing wrong.

Comment: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/LocalNotification https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/LocalNotification

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH1-SW1 followed it and built a native app but want to do the same for phonegap.

Comment: some pitfalls of local notifications: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876559/phonegap-ios-localnotification-app-crashes-on-tapping-view/9042812#9042812