# Phonegap Local notification in android and ios

Tags: notifications, phonegap-plugins, localnotification

i have develop application in phone gap.How to integrate local notification in android and iphone using phone gap.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8910119/local-notification-in-phonegap?rq=1 Possible Duplicate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Local notification in phonegap 3.3.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20979132/local-notification-in-phonegap-3-3-0)